# React Testing Library: Unable to Change Material UI DatePicker Input Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, material-ui, react-testing-library

I'm trying to change the value of the Material UI Datepicker Input with React Testing Library. But it doesn't seem to work with `fireEvent.change()`.

```js
import React from "react";
import { render, screen, waitFor, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";

import MomentUtils from "@date-io/moment";
import { DatePicker, MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from "@material-ui/pickers";

describe("DatePicker", () => {
    test("Change datepicker value", async () => {
        render(
            <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
                <DatePicker
                    label="Start Date"
                    id="startDate"
                    onChange={(date) => {
                        return undefined;
                    }}
                    value={new Date()}
                    format={"yyyy/MM/DD"}
                />
            </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
        );

        const startDateInput = (await screen.findByLabelText("Start Date")) as HTMLInputElement;
        screen.debug(startDateInput);
        fireEvent.change(startDateInput, { target: { value: "2021/01/01" } });
        expect(startDateInput.value).toBe("2021/01/01");
    });
```

Here is what jest reports:

```
console.log
    <input
      aria-invalid="false"
      class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input"
      id="startDate"
      readonly=""
      type="text"
      value="2021/08/01"
    />

expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "2021/01/01"
    Received: "2021/08/27"
```

Any suggestions are appreciated :)

Comment: This works for me. The only difference in my code is im using 

<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterMoment}>
                <DatePicker
                    label="Start Date"
                    id="startDate"
                    onChange={(date) => {
                        return undefined;
                    }}
                    value={new Date()}
                    format={"yyyy/MM/DD"}
                />
            </LocalizationProvider>

instead see docs here: https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DatePicker` by default will open the calendar view and will not allow you to provide keyboard inputs . You need to use the `KeyboardDatePicker` instead .

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";

import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import {
  KeyboardDatePicker,
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
} from "@material-ui/pickers";

const DatePickerExample = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <KeyboardDatePicker
        clearable
        label="Start Date"
        id="startDate"
        onChange={(date) => {
          setDate(date);
        }}
        value={date}
        format={"yyyy/MM/dd"}
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
};

describe("DatePicker", () => {
  test("Change datepicker value", () => {
    render(<DatePickerExample />);

    const startDateInput = screen.getByLabelText("Start Date");
    fireEvent.change(startDateInput, { target: { value: "2021/01/01" } });
    expect(startDateInput.value).toBe("2021/01/01");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and solved it this way:

```
const datepicker = screen.getByLabelText('To date')
userEvent.type(datepicker, '2021-11-09'); // type anything 
const chosenDate = screen.getByRole('button', { name: "Oct 30, 2019"}); // choose any date that the calender shows
fireEvent.click(chosenDate);
expect(chosenDate).toBeInTheDocument();
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answer worked for me, with a little modification though.

```
 const dayOfVisit = container.getByRole('textbox', { name: 'Choose date, selected date is Sep 7, 2021' })
 fireEvent.click(dayOfVisit);
 const dayInput = container.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sep 9, 2021'});
 fireEvent.click(dayInput);
 expect(dayInput).toBeInTheDocument();
```